# jQuery add attribute according to elements value

Tags: jquery, attributes

I'm trying to set an attribute to the container according to child's element value but I am getting an attribute of the first found value applied to all containers.

```
$(function () {
  $("div.column").each(function() {
    $(this).attr("my-data", $("div.column").find(".value").html());
  });
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/76mjyb2n/10/

Comment: Firstly, use `data()` to store custom information with an element. Adding a `my-data` attribute will make your HTML invalid. Secondly, there seems to be little point in adding an attribute to an element when the original value is easily accessible from the element by DOM traversal anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `$(this)` again inside the loop:

```
$(function () {
  $("div.column").each(function() {
    $(this).attr("my-data", $(this).find(".value").html());
  });
});
```

See: https://jsfiddle.net/76mjyb2n/12/

Comment: Thank you, now I get it.